# Bootstrap 3 input-group-addon and input border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Cannot remove border between `input-group-addon` and `input` when `input-group-addon` has white background.

```
<div class="input-group" style="min-height: 46px;">
  <span class="input-group-addon input_prepend" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-search-location"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control header_input" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Here example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Dp76/t2r6e3db/

Comment: how you can specify `input-group-addon` background has `white`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a border it's box-shadow.

Add this to your css code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Iulius90/t2r6e3db/6/

```
    .input-group-addon,
    .input-group-addon + input {
       box-shadow: none;
    }
```